# Exposing a method which is inside a closure

Tags: javascript, closures

When we are creating a method inside a closure it becomes private to that closure and can't be accessed until we expose it in some way.

How can it be exposed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can return a reference to it...

```
var a = function() {

   var b = function() {
      // I'm private!
      alert('go away!');
   };

   return {
      b: b // Not anymore!
   };

};
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/9uah7/).

You could also [bind it to the `window` object](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/9uah7/1/). But I prefer the method above, otherwise you are exposing it via a global variable (being a property of the `window` object).

Comment: +1.  OP, you should check out this ebook: http://addyosmani.com/blog/essentialjsdesignpatterns/.  This is known as the "Revealing Module" pattern.

Comment: thanks!can we expose it same way if its a anonymous function?

Comment: @paul Yes, `return function() { }`.

Comment: so if its a anonymous function like  (function () { 
    var privateVar = 10; 
    return { 
        publicFunc: function () {/*...*/}, 
        debug: function () { 
            debugger; 
        } 
    }; 
}());

Comment: @paul Well you are self invoking that, so nothing is assigned the `return` variable (well, `undefined` is).

Comment: @alex ! got it ...if I modify it like var add = (function () { 
    var privateVar = 10; 
    return { 
        publicFunc: function () {/*...*/}, 
        debug: function (a, b) { 
            return a+b; 
        } 
    }; 
}());

 add.debug(30,40);  it will work

Comment: @alex..thanks! I have one more question related with mixin in JS ...how you gonna use mixin in JS..any idea?

Comment: @paul I have no idea what *mixin* is sorry.

Comment: "Mixin"s are when one object inherits from multiple (abstract) parent objects, as originally done in the Flavors system in Lisp in the 80's.  The word came from Steve's Ice Cream Parlor, where you could create ice cream with mixin nuts and/or raisins and/or crumbs, etc., and end up with a different holistic result.

Comment: Surely the point about making what you wrote into an IIFE  `var a=(function.....)();` should be incorporated into your answer. Also you could include a usage. So without an IIFE `a().b()`  or with an IIFE  `a.b()`

Answer (score 9):

You need to pass it to the outside in some manner.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/T9vnn/1/

```
function someFunc() {

    var privateFunc = function() {
        alert('expose me!');
    }

    // Method 1: Directly assign it to an outer scope
    window.exposed = privateFunc;

    // Method 2: pass it out as a function argument
    someOuterFunction( privateFunc );

    // Method 3: return it
    return privateFunc;
}

someFunc()(); // alerts "expose me!"

function someOuterFunction( fn ) {
    fn(); // alerts "expose me!"
}

window.exposed(); // alerts "expose me!"
```

Comment: window is a global object . Is it a good way to use a global object to exposed a method?

Comment: @paul - I'd agree with @alex and say no. I just used it as a generic example. You can assign it to any scope to which you have access.

Comment: @paul Not really, unless you have to, like jQuery adding `jQuery` and `$` to the `window` object.

Comment: @paul: Sorry, but I'm not too familiar with them. How would you describe what you want to do?

Comment: @patrick This is another way to make  code reuse without inheritance. Consider you have a function, and you wish to use in many classes. In practice, you create a class that contains your general-purpose methods, and then use it to augment other classes. Class with these general-purpose methods is called Mixin class. It is generally not instantiated or called directly, instead it exists to provide methods to other classes.

Comment: @patrick I have accepted @alex answer since he answered it first ...but you have  more generic explanation with possible ways to expose it....thanks again

Comment: @paul: I didn't see your comments until just now. Thanks for the explanation on mixins. I had heard the term used, but never knew exactly what they were or how they were implemented. In javascript, if you wanted to add general purpose functions to a class without using inheritance, I suppose you could store them in an object, and just copy them into whatever class instance needs them. Since Functions are first class objects in javascript, you can treat them much like other data types. There's a library called `underscore.js` that you may want to take a look at. :o)

Answer (score 5):

You expose functions or properties of a closure by internally declaring them in *this* scope (which can change depending on invocation).

```
function example(val) {

    var value = val;

    this.getVal = function() {
        return value;
    }

    this.setVal = function(v) {
        value = v;
    }
}

var ex = new example(2);
ex.getVal();  // == 2
ex.setVal(4); // == null
ex.getVal();  // == 4
```

Methods declared in *this* can access variables declared using *var*, but not the other way 'round.

```
function example(val) {

    var value = val;

    var double = function(v) {
        return 2 * v;
    }

    this.getDouble = function() {
        return double(value);
    }
}


var ex = new example(2);
ex.getDouble(); // == 4
```

The *function* closes over the scope. What you want to do is to return a reference to a function that has access to the scope you require so you can invoke it at a later point.

If you need to create a function that calls a specific method at some later point,

```
var ex = new example(2);
var delayed_call = function() {
    return(ex.getDouble()); // == 4, when called
}
setTimeout(delayed_call, 1000);
```

If scoping is an issue,

```
var ex = new example(2);
var delayed_call = (function(ex_ref) {
    return function() {
        return(ex_ref.getDouble()); // == 4, when called
    }
})(ex); // create a new scope and capture a reference to ex as ex_ref
setTimeout(delayed_call, 1000);
```

You can inline most of this with the less readable example of,

```
setTimeout((function(ex_ref) {
    return function() {
        return(ex_ref.getDouble()); // == 4, when called
    })(new example(2))) 
    , 1000
);
```

*setTimeout* is just a convenient way of demonstrating execution in new scope.

```
var ex = new example(2);
var delayed_call = function() {
    return(ex.getDouble());
}
delayed_call(); // == 4
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance purposes you can invoke it this way:

```
var a = (function(){
   function _a(){}
   _a.prototype = (function(){
     var _test = function(){ console.log("test"); };
     return {
       test: _test
     }
   }());

  return new _a();
}());

// usage
var x = a;
x.test(); // "test"
```