# How to pass a argument from anchor tag onclick to a function inside document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have a function inside document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    function myFunction(id) {
        alert(id);
    };
})
```

I want to pass an argument from an anchor tag like that.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction(1)">Item 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction(2)">Item 2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction(3)">Item 3</a>
```

I know myFunction is not in global scope. That is why it will not going to work. So is there any way to pass an argument from anchor tag to a function inside document ready?

Comment: And why did you put that function inside `$(document).ready(...)` in the first place? ... I mean there is no need it being a standard function declaration.

Comment: You dont need the document to be ready just to define that function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exposing a method which is inside a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404786/exposing-a-method-which-is-inside-a-closure)

Comment: Suppose I have a function called test1() inside document ready and also have a function outside document ready called test2(). If i call test1 from test2 then how it will be possible? I have some function inside document ready, so I have to call it from that function.

Comment: @AshisBiswas Posted a link for you in my previous comment

Comment: ok let me check. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to put the function in document.ready, that would only be needed if you need to get an element from the DOM for your selector to find it.

So either omit that, or do it the proper way and assign an event listener and handler. To pass different things from your `<a>`, you could use a data-attribute, for example.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log($(this).data('foo'));
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-foo="1">Item 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-foo="2">Item 2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-foo="3">Item 3</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using jQuery event binding.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    function myFunction(id) {
        alert(id);
    };
    
    $(document).on("click", "a", function(event) {
      var arg = $(this).attr("data-arg");
      myFunction(arg);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-arg="1">Item 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-arg="2">Item 2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-arg="3">Item 3</a>
```